# A script to list all the exceptions and their number of occurrence

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have coded an analyzer which analyzes a file, and returns different results: `GOOD`, `BAD`, `Unexpected exception :` which is followed by different exceptions... My `makefile` runs this analyzer on a set of files one by one, and puts the whole result in one file `output.txt`. So the `output.txt` looks like as follows:

```
file "f1.txt"
...
GOOD
file "f2.txt"
...
Unexpected exception : exception1
...
Unexpected exception : exception2
...
```

Now I would like to write a shell script `summary` which summarizes `output.txt`, especially lists what exceptions are raised and their number of occurrence. It should like like:

```
exception1 : 9
exception2 : 15
...
```

The order of the exceptions has no importance, (well, if it is sorted by the number of the occurrence, it would be better)...

I know `grep "Unexpected exception" output.txt | wc -l` will return the number of occurrence of all the exceptions, but I do need to know the occurrence for each exception raised...

Does anyone know how to write this `summary` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F ' : ' '$1=="Unexpected exception"{a[$2]++} END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk would probably be your best choice. I highly recommend looking at [the GNU Awk User Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for more information, as awk is extremely powerful and useful in situations like yours.

This will do what you want (a little more readable than the other answer)...

```
awk '/Unexpected exception/ { for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) freq[$i]++ } END { for (word in freq) printf "%s : %d\n", word, freq[word] }' output.txt
```

Where `i = 4` is the location of the string you want to use (`$1=Unexpected $2=exception $3=: $4=exception1`. Try changing it to `i = 2` and see what you get.