# A perl script to list all the exceptions and their number of occurrence

Tags: regex, perl, bash, awk

(I am looking for a solution in Perl for this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944154/a-script-to-list-all-the-exceptions-and-their-number-of-occurrence), because the solution in `awk` doesn't always work well for some reasons).

Here is the abstract of the goal: I have a file `output.txt`, it contains `Unexpected exception :` which is followed by different exceptions... For instance, it looks like

```
...
Unexpected exception : exception1
...
Unexpected exception : exception2
...
```

Now I would like to write a shell script `summary` which summarizes `output.txt`, especially lists what exceptions are raised and their number of occurrence. It should like like:

```
exception1 : 9
exception2 : 15
...
```

The order of the exceptions has no importance, (well, if it is sorted by the number of the occurrence, it would be better)...

A `awk`solution is:

```
awk -F ' : ' '$1=="Unexpected exception"{a[$2]++} END{for (i in a) print "  ", i,a[i]}' $1
```

but I don't know why sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. That's why I am looking for a solution in Perl. Someone proposed

```
perl -lne '$a{$1}++ if (/^(Unexpected exception) : (.*?)\s*$/); END { for $i (keys %a) { print " ", $i, $a{$i} } }' $1
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20665308/702977)), but it returns `Unexpected exception177` where `177` is the total number of the exceptions. That is not what I want.

Could anyone propose a good solution in Perl?

Comment: Based on your description, this is completely doable in `awk`. If you give an example of the edge cases when the `awk` script doesn't work maybe we could fix it.

Comment: Instead of just changing the language, perhaps you could try to figure out why the `awk` solution is breaking.

Comment: I understand your opinion, but my `output.txt` has dozens of Mo, it is hard to debug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your perl backreferences are incorrect:

```
perl -lne '$a{$1}++ if (/^(Unexpected exception) : (.*?)\s*$/)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-$1 ^^^^^-$2
```

You want

```
 $a{$2}++
```

instead. Or convert that first `()` to a non-capturing group: `(?:Un....)`

Comment: Thanks for that... Is it possible to order it, based on the occurrence?