# Sort an output (an array) in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

(I am looking for a better solution in `Perl` for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668356/a-perl-script-to-list-all-the-exceptions-and-their-number-of-occurrence)).

Here is the abstract of the goal: I have a file `output.txt`, it contains `Unexpected exception :` which is followed by different exceptions... For instance, it looks like

```
...
Unexpected exception : exception1
...
Unexpected exception : exception2
...
```

Here is a Perl script which summarizes `output.txt` by listing what exceptions are raised and their number of occurrence:

```
perl -lne '$a{$2}++ if (/^(Unexpected exception) : (.*?)\s*$/); END { for $i (keys %a) { print "   ", $i, " ", $a{$i} } }' $1
```

The result looks like:

```
exception2 : 15
exception3 : 7
exception1 : 9
...
```

Now I would like to improve this script, so that the exceptions could be listed in an alphabetical order:

```
exception1 : 9
exception2 : 15
exception3 : 7
...
```

Does anyone know how to change this script to achieve this goal?

Additionally, I may want to list the exceptions in a decreasing order of the occurrence:

```
exception15 : 20
exception2 : 15
exception1 : 9
exception3 : 7
...
```

Does anyone know to do it?

Comment: just do `all that stuff | sort`

Comment: @RedCricket that is cool... it answers to my first question... Do you have an idea for the second one?

Comment: `man sort` will answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort by exception name

```
perl -lne '$a{$2}++ if (/^(Unexpected exception) : (.*?)\s*$/); END { for $i (sort keys %a) { print "   ", $i, " ", $a{$i} } }' $1
```

Sort by occurances

```
perl -lne '$keys{$2}++ if (/^(Unexpected exception) : (.*?)\s*$/); END { for $i (sort { $keys{$b} <=> $keys{$a} } keys %keys) { print "   ", $i, " ", $keys{$i} } }' $1
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this script-version is more readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %exceptions;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $exceptions{$1}++ if (m/^Unexpected exception : (.*?)\s*$/);
}

print "Sorted by exception name:\n";
foreach my $exc (sort keys %exceptions) {
    print "$exc : $exceptions{$exc}\n";
}

print "Sorted by exception count:\n";
foreach my $exc (sort { $exceptions{$b} <=> $exceptions{$a} } keys %exceptions) {
    print "$exc : $exceptions{$exc}\n";
}

__DATA__
Unexpected exception : exception1
Unexpected exception : exception2
Unexpected exception : exception2
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl/sort/uniq solution. Strip the leading text, sort, then count:

```
perl -pe 's/Unexpected exception : //' input.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

To sort by number of occurrences, add an extra `sort -g`:

```
perl -pe 's/Unexpected exception : //' input.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -g
```